# Recuperar parâmetro enviado para uma modal e realizar consulta MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

Preciso recuperar parâmetro enviado a uma modal bootstrap, realizar uma consulta no banco e mostrar resultado em um campo de texto para o usuário, o que tenho é isso:

O envio do parâmetro para a modal

```
<i class="icon-large  icon-book" onclick="VerComentario()" IdCandidato=<?php echo $IdCandidato; ?>></i>
```

A chamada da modal

```
     // Chamada da janela modal para ver o Comentário
function VerComentario() {
    $("#VerComentario").modal({
        backdrop: false
    });
    $("#VerComentario .modal-header h3").html("Observação Cadastrada");
    $("#VerComentario").modal("show");
}
```

Na modal tenho esse SQL

```
    <?php

    $IdCandidato = $_GET['IdCandidato'];

    require_once('../Connections/conCurriculoCocari.php');
        $query = "SELECT * FROM observacao  WHERE id_candidato = $IdCandidato ";
        $result = mysql_query($query) or die ('Error (' . mysql_errno() . ') ' . mysql_error());
    ?>
```

Mas o parâmetro não está sendo enviado, preciso receber o mesmo, enviar para a modal para fazer o select e mostrar o resultado para o usuário

Comment: A sua pergunta não está mto clara. O modal é uma janela que abre, não está ligado à função de enviar dados para o lado do servidor. Quem faz isso é AJAX. Faz sentido o que eu escreví? tem algum código/chamada de ajax?

Comment: Olá @Sergio, valeu pelo comentário, estou tentando fazer algo como explicado nesse post, mas não ficou muito claro para mim, veja:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11003679/dynamically-load-information-to-twitter-bootstrap-modal

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sempre que você quiser guardar alguma informação em um atributo de `<tag>` que não seja HTML válido você tem que usar o prefixo `data-`.

Considere o seguinte HTML:

```
<div id="minha-div" data-mensagem="Olá Mundo!"></div>
```

Você pode recuperar uma informação da seguinte maneira (usando jQuery):

```
alert( $("#minha-div").data("mensagem") );
```

Veja no JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/7J2Ru/

Comment: Obrigado Andrey, essa dica me ajudou muito, valeu, obrigado também ao @Sergio, entendi sua colocação.